# Can a single character be underlined in alt text in img element

Tags: html, css, image, alt

We have a need to underline a character in a client's name.  How do I do it in alt attribute of img element?

```
<img alt="ab<u>c</u>def" />
<img alt="ab&lt;u&gt;c&lt;/u&gt;def" />
<img alt="ab<span style='text-decoration:underline;'>c</span>def" />
```

I expect the output to be underlined 'c' but actual output is literal.

Comment: The value of the `alt`-attribute normally is only visible (A) as long as the image isn't loaded, (B) images are disabled, which is the same as A in the end or (C) in a css declaration like so: `content: attr(alt)`.

Answer (score 2):

It can't. HTML entities don't work in tag attributes, only between tags.